# Chrome console table add colors

Tags: google-chrome, logging, colors, console, google-chrome-devtools

This is an example of how we can log in chrome dev tools with colors:

```
console.log('%c test1 ', 'background: black; color: green')
```

I was wondering whether we can log with table and colors and the same time ?

Comment: It [doesn't have](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#tabledata_columns) such a parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no styling capabilities on the `console.table` function, as per the [Console API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console).

However, I was able to come up with a really hacky solution for styling a `console.log` statement as if it were a table. This is probably not going to be good enough, but it was pretty fun to make.

There were many limitations, like not being able to set the `width` and `height` properties. My workaround was to pad the text with spaces to match the longest property name/value.

```js
(function() {
    function getProperties(obj) {
        var props = [];

        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                props.push(prop);
            }
        }

        return props;
    }

    function getLongestTextLength(objArray) {
        var longest = 0;

        for (var obj of objArray) {
            for (var prop in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    var length = Math.max(prop.length, obj[prop].length);
                    if (length > longest) longest = length;
                }
            }
        }

        return longest;
    }

    console.fancyTable = function(objArray) {
        var objProto = objArray[0];
        var args = [];
        var header = '';

        var baseStyles = 'padding: 2px; line-height: 18px;';
        var baseBorders = 'border-top: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black; '
        var headerStyles = baseStyles + baseBorders + 'font-weight: bold; background: lightcoral;';
        var lastHeaderStyles = baseStyles + 'font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid black; background: lightcoral;';
        var rowStyles = baseStyles + baseBorders + 'background: lightblue;'
        var lastRowStyles = baseStyles + 'border: 1px solid black;  background: lightblue;'

        var props = getProperties(objProto);
        var longestTextLength = getLongestTextLength(objArray);

        for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
            var prop = props[i];

            while (prop.length < longestTextLength) {
                prop += ' ';
            }

            header += '%c' + prop + ' ';

            if (i === props.length - 1) {
                args.push(lastHeaderStyles);
            } else {
                args.push(headerStyles);
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
            var obj = objArray[i];

            header += '\n';

            for (var j = 0; j < props.length; j++) {
                var val = obj[props[j]];

                while (val.length < longestTextLength) {
                    val += ' ';
                }

                header += '%c' + val + ' ';

                if (j === props.length - 1) {
                    args.push(lastRowStyles);
                } else {
                    args.push(rowStyles);
                }
            }
        }

        args.unshift(header);
        console.log.apply(this, args);
    }
})();


function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

// create some test objects
var john = new Person("John", "Smith");
var jane = new Person("Jane", "Doe");
var emily = new Person("Emily", "Jones");

var peopleToLog = [john, jane, emily];

console.fancyTable(peopleToLog);
```

[image: Example]

I'll make some improvements if I can, and perhaps publish it for the giggles.

Comment: !!!!! it's unbelievable !!!!! thanks a lot, I'm gonna use that enhance it! it will be really great if you can create some library and publish it... thanks a lot

Comment: Haha thanks. I'll see what I can do. It's going to be pretty limited and hacky obviously.

Comment: Brilliant. In 2022 it has a little bug in chrome, in order to fix it it's necessary to clean the style before the newline.

header += '%c\n';
args.push("");